# Not able to get actual uri of image clicked from camera

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap, android-camera2

After implementing `Camera2 Api` for clicking image I am getting image in this listener

```
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            Image img                   = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            final Image.Plane[] planes  = img.getPlanes();
            final ByteBuffer buffer     = planes[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] byteArray            = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(byteArray);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            uri = getImageUri(getContext(), bmp);
        }
    };
```

I tried to parse the `Image` to `Bitmap` in order to get the image uri using this method

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
        this.saveToInternalStorage(inImage);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "CAPTURE" + captureCount, null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

But the image uri, which I get from above method, when I try to use it for displaying image in `ImageView` doesnot shows up any thing but I can see the clicked image in gallery.

Image uri which I get starts like `external/**/<some number>`

> What I am trying to do is I want to get uri of clicked image and use
>   that uri to edit it.

If there is any other way to edit image may be like using bitmap or some other form pls do mention.

Comment: so what exactly `Uri.parse(path);` returns?

Comment: content://media/external/images/media/44974

Comment: now this is a correct `Uri` - you can use it with `ContentResolver`

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: read [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver) official documentation

Comment: Thanx for showing some way.

Comment: you can check for the basic properties by using for example `getType` and `query` methods and get the content of your `Uri` by calling `openInputStream` method

Comment: @Thullo Please check my answer. You can use FileProvider.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161899/4657385